# cannot add records to aws elastic search from my lambda code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I use the following to add the data I have in dynamodb to elastic search:

```
https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/aws/category/amazon-elasticsearch-service/?nc1=h_ls


var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var path = require('path');

//Object for all the ElasticSearch Domain Info
var esDomain = {
region: process.env.RegionForES,
endpoint: process.env.EndpointForES,
index: process.env.IndexForES,
doctype: 'onboardingrecords'
};
//AWS Endpoint from created ES Domain Endpoint
var endpoint = new AWS.Endpoint(esDomain.endpoint);
//The AWS credentials are picked up from the environment.
var creds = new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS');

console.log('Loading function');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
//console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
console.log(JSON.stringify(esDomain));

event.Records.forEach((record) => {
    console.log(record.eventID);
    console.log(record.eventName);
    console.log('DynamoDB Record: %j', record.dynamodb);

    var dbRecord = JSON.stringify(record.dynamodb);
    postToES(dbRecord, context, callback);
});
 };

function postToES(doc, context, lambdaCallback) {
var req = new AWS.HttpRequest(endpoint);

req.method = 'POST';
req.path = path.join('/', esDomain.index, esDomain.doctype);
req.region = esDomain.region;
req.headers['presigned-expires'] = false;
req.headers['Host'] = endpoint.host;
req.body = doc;

var signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(req, 'es'); // es: service code
signer.addAuthorization(creds, new Date());

var send = new AWS.NodeHttpClient();
send.handleRequest(req, null, function(httpResp) {
    var respBody = '';
    httpResp.on('data', function(chunk) {
        respBody += chunk;
    });
    httpResp.on('end', function(chunk) {
        console.log('Response: ' + respBody);
        lambdaCallback(null, 'Lambda added document ' + doc);
    });
  }, function(err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
    lambdaCallback('Lambda failed with error ' + err);
});
}
```

So dynamo db successfully trigger lamda and then In the above code when I debug it I see that everything is good up to this:

```
send.handleRequest(req, null, function(httpResp) {
    var respBody = '';
    httpResp.on('data', function (chunk) {
        respBody += chunk;
    });
    httpResp.on('end', function (chunk) {
        console.log('Response: ' + respBody);
        lambdaCallback(null,'Lambda added document ' + doc);
    });
}, function(err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
    lambdaCallback('Lambda failed with error ' + err);
});
 }
```

So in the above this part  respBody += chunk; is always empty and nothing is added to resBody. Also when I check the aws elastic search I do not see anything added but at the same time I do not see any error in my lambda console? Is the code wrong or am I missing anything?

Comment: AWSNodeHttp client is not very nice... I've been using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/ along with this plugin to get the IAM role https://github.com/TheDeveloper/http-aws-es.

Comment: I can post a code sample if it helps.

On a different note altogether ... isn't dynamodb integrated with elasticsearch now. Do you even have to do this?

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/08/amazon-dynamodb-elasticsearch-integration/

Comment: @razboy thanks a lot can u please post the sample code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For my import I do the following. In the elastic search cluster I set the IAM policy to allow the account access to the cluster. Something like below, you might want to be more restrictive.

```
"Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234:root"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

In my lambda I do the following to create a client connection which uses the AWS creds available to lambda:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const connectionClass = require('http-aws-es');
const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

const client = elasticsearch.Client({
  log: 'trace',
  hosts: 'host',
  connectionClass: connectionClass,
  amazonES: {
    region: 'region',
    credentials: new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS')
  }
});
```

Then you should be able to use the client as per this [doco](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/). Npm install the dependencies [http-aws-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-aws-es), elasticsearch and aws-sdk (this one is for dev only).

You should be able to replace the entire `postToEs` with `client.bulk`
[build insert](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-bulk)